# running a PowerShell command sp 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to create a site map with a PowerShell command from this example:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/opal/archive/2010/04/13/generate-sharepoint-2010-sitemap-with-windows-powershell.aspx

My actions: I copied the code into a file named `New-SPSiteMap`

I opened the PowerShell and wrote

```
New-SPSiteMap –Url http://centerportal –SavePath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\sitemap.xml
```

The error I get is:

```
The term 'New-SPSiteMap' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, 
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:14
+ New-SPSiteMap <<<<  -Url http://mossdev2010  -SavePath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\sitemap.xml
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-SPSiteMap:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the `New-SPSiteMap` function available you have to execute the script containing the function:

```
& .\New-SPSiteMap.ps1
New-SPSiteMap –Url http://centerportal –SavePath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\sitemap.xml
```

Alliteratively, you could turn the PowerShell script into a "function" that is callable like this:

```
.\New-SPSiteMap.ps1 -Url http://centerportal –SavePath C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\sitemap.xml
```

All you have to do is remove the function declaration `function New-SPSiteMap`:

```
param($SavePath="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\80\SiteMap.xml", $Url="http://sharepoint")

function New-Xml
{
    param($RootTag="urlset",$ItemTag="url", $ChildItems="*", $SavePath="C:\SiteMap.xml")

    Begin {
        $xml="<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
        <urlset xmlns=""http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"">"
    }
    Process {
        $xml += " <$ItemTag>"
        foreach ($child in $_){
        $Name = $child
        $xml += " <$ChildItems>$url/$child</$ChildItems>"
    }
        $xml += " </$ItemTag>"
    }
    End {
        $xml += "</$RootTag>"
        $xmltext=[xml]$xml
        $xmltext.Save($SavePath)
    }
}

$web = Get-SPWeb $url
$list = $web.Lists | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.Items} | ForEach-Object -Process {$_.url.Replace(" ","%20")}

# excludes directories you don’t want in sitemap. you can put multiple lines here:

$list = $list | ? {$_ -notmatch "_catalogs"} 
$list = $list | ? {$_ -notmatch "Reporting%20Templates"} 
$list = $list | ? {$_ -notmatch "Reporting%20Metadata"} 
$list | New-Xml -RootTag urlset -ItemTag url -ChildItems loc -SavePath $SavePath
```

Comment: no it is runing but it is not createing the site map if You can write down on the site to the code i should put inside the file

Comment: i run
PS C:\> .\New-SPSiteMap.ps1 -Url http://centerportal/ -SavePath C:\sitemap.xml
and i get the error
The term 'New-Xml' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was inc
luded, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\New-SPSiteMap.ps1:11 char:16
+ $list | New-Xml <<<<  -RootTag urlset -ItemTag url -ChildItems loc -SavePath
$SavePath
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (New-Xml:String) [], CommandNotF
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundExcepti